# authentication check with authentication check.gif

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

JHipster project uses an authentication check with **authentication_check.gif?timestamp**. How a .gif file can authenticate a logged in user?

$http.GET("protected/authentication_check.gif?time="+timestamp+").then(/*Handlers*/)

on failure it gives 401 unauthorized error.

for more ref:
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/599

Answer (score 1):

You must use an old version of JHipster as it is no longer used.

Anyway it depends on the authentication scheme you chose, if your app uses HTTP session authentication then when it requests an image, it includes the session cookie and spring security checks whether your session is still valid and for an authenticated user. The fact that this is an image is not important.